# Yates-Grundy draw-by-draw sampling inclusion probabilities

Tags: pr.probability, sampling

Is there an efficient algorithm to calculate the inclusion probabilities (the probability that an item will be included in a sample) in the Yates-Grundy draw-by-draw sampling?

**Sampling description**: We have $n$ items each with probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_n$ of being selected in the first draw. We then sample without replacement the items one by one with probabilities proportional to the original $p_i$.

I looked in the book Brewer, Muhammad: Sampling with Unequal Probabilities and this is described on p. 24, but the equation (2.2.1) seems to work for sample of size 2 only.

Comment: How many items are you sampling?

Comment: @YuvalPeres About 10. I am calculating this now by exhaustive enumeration of all the possibilities, which is even for this small number too computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to exist no efficient algorithm to calculate the inclusion probabilities in the Yates-Grundy draw-by-draw sampling procedure—see the comment on "weighted random sampling without replacement with defined weights" (WRS) in [Efraimidis (2015)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-24024-4_12). However, in practice, you can use fast simulation algorithms to obtain point estimates with very tight confidence intervals—see [Efraimidis and Spirakis (2006)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002001900500298X?via%3Dihub).